# Nginx - sub-url and separated service

Tags: nginx

It's possible in nginx to do something like:

```
location /backend {
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}
location /{
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_frontend;
}
```

It works when I go to /backend but if I go to /backend/something_more I'm redirected to /something_more

Comment: Does it work better if you do `location ~ ^/backend {` ?

Comment: @Jaw.sh Unfortunately, the same.

Comment: Are you positive that the app isn't redirecting requests? Have you tried removing other location blocks to see if there's interference?

Comment: @Jaw.sh
I commented second location and it's still the same.
I'm just wondering if regexp is ok, maybe it should be something after /backend not (only) before